# No horizontal line in \thanks on a title page

Tags: footnotes, titles, rules

Folks,
happy holidays.

A quick question: when I put `\thanks` in the below code, I don't see the horizontal line (i.e. separator) that I see in the usual footnote command. I think the issue is with the `\begin{titlingpage}`. Can anyone help how to get the horizontal separator back in the game? Here is the full code and happy holidays!

Note: I am using the `titling` package to have abstract, author, title, thanks all on the same page...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\author{My Name\thanks{ABC University}}
\title{Happy Holidays!}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{titlingpage}
\begin{abstract}
{Happy Holidays!}

\noindent \vspace{5mm}
\noindent \textit{Key Words}: Happy Holidays!
\vspace{1mm}
\noindent \textit{Lit} Code: Happy Holidays!
\end{abstract}
\end{titlingpage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happy holidays! :D

Use `\usethanksrule` inside the `titlingpage` environment:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\author{My Name\thanks{ABC University}}
\title{Happy Holidays!}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{titlingpage}
\usethanksrule % <-- here
\begin{abstract}
{Happy Holidays!}

\noindent \vspace{5mm}
\noindent \textit{Key Words}: Happy Holidays!
\vspace{1mm}
\noindent \textit{Lit} Code: Happy Holidays!
\end{abstract}
\end{titlingpage}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: That's a strange way to name it! \cancelthanksrule *prevents* suppression of the footnote rule for thanks?

Comment: @DonaldArseneau Now that you mention, indeed, the package does have a `\usethanksrule` that does the same.  The name `\cancelthanksrule` uses the original `\@bsfootnoterule` for the rule, and `\usethanksrule` uses a document-level `\thanksrule`, so I guess the latter can be redefined, and `\cancelthanksrule` cancels that redefinition...